# fatal error when I run this php code

Tags: php

I want to connect this php to tpl.

But it gives me fatal error when I try to run.

I added smarty to php to show those data on tpl file but still has problem.

```
<?php
include('developer.php');
if( $xml = simplexml_load_file(url))
{
foreach($xml->campaign as $campaigns) 
{   
$camp_name = $campaignsl->name;
$camp_dec= $campaigns->description;
$camp_payout= $campaigns->payout;
$camp_url= $campaigns->url;
$smarty->assign( 'camp_name', $camp_name);
$smarty->assign( 'camp_dec', $camp_dec);
$smarty->assign( 'camp_payout', $camp_payout);
$smarty->assign( 'camp_url', $camp_url);
$smarty->display('link.tpl');
}
}
?>
```

and this is the tpl file (link.tpl).

```
<table width="100%" class="widget-tbl">
<tr class="titles">
<td align="center">Name</td>
<td align="center">Description</td>
<td align="center">amount</td>
<td align="center">Link</td>
</tr>
<tbody id="tablelist">
{foreach item=item from=$campaigns}
<tr>
<td align="center">{$camp_name}</td>
<td align="center">{$camp_dec}</td>
<td align="center">{$camp_payout}</td>
<td align="center">{$camp_url}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}    
</tbody>
```

Comment: What is the fatal error you're getting?

Comment: What fatal error? Can you give use the trace? I think it's the `$` missing at the first part of the code.

Comment: Also please be aware that if you assign smarty values in a loop (in PHP) only the values of the last loop will be passed to smarty!

Comment: ( Fatal error: Call to a member function totalResults() on a non-object in link.tpl.php on line 97 )

Comment: The code you posted has got nothing in it with `totalResults()`, please post the relevant code. (My guess is that it is somewhere located in your .tpl file)

Comment: Are you really showing everything from template-file? Which line is 97?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is your `$url` variable (as also pointed by @maxime-lorant) in the following statement:

```
if( $xml = simplexml_load_file($url)) // Use $url not url
```

Second, you're doing `$camp_name = $campaignsl->name;` and `$campaignsl` is undefined!

Third, you're not assigning `$campaign` to smarty template and you are executing a loop on it.

Try the following:

```
if( $xml = simplexml_load_file($url))
{
    $smarty->assign('campaigns', $xml->campaign);
    $smarty->display('link.tpl');
}
```

Then in your template:

```
{foreach item=item from=$campaigns}
    <tr>
        <td align="center">{$item->name}</td>
        <td align="center">{$item->description}</td>
        <td align="center">{$item->payout}</td>
        <td align="center">{$item->url}</td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forget a `$` at the parsing of your XML file:

```
if( $xml = simplexml_load_file(url))
```

Replace this by `if( $xml = simplexml_load_file($url))`. You may also check if this variable is initialized, since you're at the begin of the file...